# display connected User to post

Tags: plugins

I've created connection between post type event and users, via posts 2 posts plugin, also i added the function to register the connection:

```
p2p_register_connection_type( array(
    'name' => 'multiple_authors',
    'from' => 'event',
    'to' => 'user',
    'to_query_vars' => array( 'role' => 'editor' )
) );
```

As the [wiki](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Posts-2-Users), i need to add this line to display list of connected users:

```
// To get a list of users connected to a certain post, you can write:

$users = get_users( array(
  'connected_type' => 'multiple_authors',
  'connected_items' => $post
) );
```

but not working with me, can you advice ?

Answer (score 1):

That code retrieves the information, it doesn't do anything with it. you have to echo out the data, expect `$users` to contain an array of `WP_User` objects

e.g.

```
$users = get_users( array(
  'connected_type' => 'multiple_authors',
  'connected_items' => $post
) );

foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    echo '<p>'.$user->name.'</p>;
}
```